# Prism 5 Wpf - The Login Window Shows me twice

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I'm developing a Login window in visual studio 2013 and I installed the Prism 5 WPF for desktop and for Dependency Injection Unity. I have a problem, my window login shows me twice, I don’t find the error, please help solve this problem:

Bootstrapper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper{
    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell(){     
        return new MainWindow();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell(){
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(){
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
        ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(SeguridadModule));
    }
}
```

MainWindow is:

```
<Window x:Class="RalWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:LoginControl="clr-namespace:RalWpf.Modules.Seguridad.Views;assembly=RalWpf.Modules.Seguridad"        
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    xmlns:regions="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions"
    Title="Church Management System" Height="530" Width="830">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resource/Image/background.jpg" />
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Name="MenuRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MenuRegion" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"  Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
    <Grid Margin="4,4,4,4" Grid.Row="1">
        <Border Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" Margin="4" Height="291" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

SeguridadModule.cs

```
public class SeguridadModule : IModule{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public SeguridadModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager) {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize(){
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(Views.UserLoginView));
        _container.RegisterType<Object, Views.UserLoginView>(ViewNames.UserLoginView);
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging program in SegurididadModule.cs I have this message:  source code not found ServiceLocatorImpIBase.cs
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the file App.xaml delete StartupUri and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Test your program with `ContentControl`

```
<ContentControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" Margin="4" Height="291" />
```

Instead of `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" Margin="4" Height="291" />
```

Also use `VisualStudio` `Find All` to check all of the solution codes include something like this:

```
regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"].Add(....)
```

Make them as `comment` (`// regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"]....`) and run again...

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried your suggestion and the same problem, login window shows me twice

Comment: Are you sure you added this view (`login`) just once to `RegionManager` in your codes? What happen if you comment this line? : `_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(Views.UserLoginView));`

Comment: When I comment this line _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(Views.UserLoginView)); shows me twice the main windows

Comment: When you comment `RegisterViewWithRegion`, you should not see any `login view` inside the main window. Is it correct? If your view is not registered in the `RegionManager` how you see it? Fully `Clean` the `Debug` folder and `Rebuild` all of your projects again and tell me about it...!

Comment: Yes, when I comment RegisterViewWithRegion I don't see login view inside the main window only main window but twice, also I commented in SeguridadModule.cs the method ConfigureModuleCatalog() this lines ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;     moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(SeguridadModule)); the same problem, shows me  main window twice, if you like, I could send you my program, it is not big